# Why isn't my code writing the output to the file created?

Tags: python

I tried writing my own script in Python that takes the output from the "iplist" variable and prints it to a text file, however I'm stuck as to why the script will create the file but not print anything? I've been stuck on this for a day now, and nothing I've found online has seemed to help me :/ Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

```
import socket
import time as t
from os import path


def ip_list(dest):

    iplist = socket.gethostbyname_ex(socket.gethostname())
    date = t.localtime(t.time())
    name = "IP addresses on %d_%d_%d.txt" % (date[1], date[2], date[0] % 100)

    if not (path.isfile(name)):
        file = open(name, 'w')
        for str in iplist:
            print >>f, str
        f.close() ## has to match open indentation

if __name__ == '__main__':
    destination = "C:\\Users\\kl\\Desktop\\python files\\"
    ip_list("destination")
    raw_input("Done!")
```

I should also add that I have attempted to use the "f.write()" command as well, not that that might be of much help?

Comment: Just FYI, this will only print if the file doesn't exist. Also, you have the line `f.write(x)`, but `x` has no value.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to remove that, good catch. It still won't write even with that removed... :(

Comment: `print >>f, str` should be `print >>file, str` or rename `file = open(name, 'w')` to `f = open(name, 'w')`. you could use `write()` as well (instead of `print >>f, str`), `f.write(str)`

Comment: I literally just caught that just before reading that, and now I feel really.... special :) I still appreciate the answer, I'm using Atom to write my code and the "file" variable was showing up in Blue, which made me automatically assume it was important/built in. Now I know.

Comment: Yupp, you shouldn't use keywords for variables...neither `file` nor `str`